# XamlParseException in windows Phone Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I am trying to create my first Windows phone application but I keep getting this "XamlParseException" thrown at me.It looks like the error is coming from the InitializeComponent() method which is a shock because it was automatically created by VS.

Here is the Exception :

XamlParseException
Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Loaded'. [Line: 14 Position: 39]

Here is the code behind :

```
namespace WinHomeWork1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            myTextBox.Focus();
        }

        private void ClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myTextBox.Text.CompareTo("1 2 3 4") == 0)
            {
                myTextBlock.Text = "You have won!";
            }
            else
                myTextBlock.Text = "You have Lost";
        }
}
}
```

Here is the Xaml Code :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="WinHomeWork1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Brahman Initiative" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="108 mintes" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="myTextBox" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" />
            <Button Content="Go" Height="74" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="234,88,0,0" Name="ClickMe" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" Click="ClickMe_Click" />
            <TextBlock Height="68" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,88,0,0" Name="myTextBlock" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

The program has only 3 elements, 1) A TextBox 2) A TextBlock and a 3) Button. The user inputs data into the textBox then clicks a "Go" button, if the input is "1 2 3 4" the app will display "You have Won" in the textBlock, if any other input has been entered it will display " You have lost".Please Help, I do not know any Xaml so I can't play around with the Xaml code.

Comment: Please add the XAML code. (copy paste from MainPage.xaml file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parameter `e` in your `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded` to an instance of the  `RoutedEventArgs` class:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded event handler method. It should be like this:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.Focus();
}
```